# European Regional Development Fund realisation and result indicators list

Tags: europe

Operational Programs from the *European Regional Development Fund (ERDF)* are using indicators to describe their objectives

Realization indicators (here, with their labels in French):

- RC**O**001: Entreprises bénéficiant d'un soutien (dont : micro, petites, moyennes,
  grandes), Unit of measure: Entreprises
- RC**O**004: Entreprises bénéficiant d’un soutien non financier
  ...

Result indicators:

- RC**R**001: Emplois crées dans des entités bénéficiant d'un soutien, Unit of Measure: Emplois à temps plein (ETP) annuels

Does a convenient open data resource exists that list them, to avoid copy-pasting their codes and labels from a pdf document?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a candidate csv file on a web page named:
[*2021-2027 ERDF-CF-JTF Common Indicator metadata*](https://cohesiondata.ec.europa.eu/2021-2027-Indicators/2021-2027-ERDF-CF-JTF-Common-Indicator-metadata/4t73-mihb)

It's a semicolon separated csv, that gives these informations:

```
1. Indicator code
2. Indicator name
2b. Indicator code and short name  (open data name)
3. Measurement unit
4. Type of indicator
5. Baseline
6. Milestone 2024
7. Target 2029
8. Policy objective (asterisks)
8b. PO (IGJ original)
9. Indicator usage by specific objective (Annex I + asterisks)
9b. Indicator listing by Specific objective (IGJ original listing in Annex 1)
10. Definition and concepts
11. Data collection
12. Time measurement achieved
13. Aggregation issues
14. Reporting
15. References
16. Corresponding corporate indicator
17. Notes
18. Link to 2014-2020 common indicators Order by annex 1
    Order by SO Order by output / result    
0. ERDF 0. COHESION FUND (72)   
0. Just transition Fund (64)
```

for these indicators:

RCO01, RCO02, RCO03, RCO04, RCO05, RCR82, RCO06, RCO07, RCO08, RCO10,
RCO96, RCR01, RCR102, RCR02, RCR03, RCR04, RCR05, RCR06, RCR07, RCR08,
RCO13, RCO14, RCR11, RCR12, RCR13, RCO15, RCO103, RCR17, RCR18, RCR19,
RCR25, RCO16, RCO101, RCR97, RCR98, RCO41, RCO42, RCR53, RCR54, RCO18,
RCO19, RCO20, RCO104, RCO123, RCR26, RCR29, RCR105, RCO22, RCO97, RCR31
RCR32, RCO23, RCO105, RCO124, RCR33, RCR34, RCO24, RCO122, RCO25, RCO106 [...]

In example:

```
RCR81   Completion of joint training schemes    RCR81 Interreg: Completion of joint training schemes    participants    result  0   not required    >0  Use in all policy objectives, whenever relevant Interreg    Use in all specific objectives, whenever relevant   Interreg    The indicator counts the number of  participants completing the joint trainings schemes organised by supported projects. Completion should be documented by the training organisers either through a record of the confirmed completions or by issuing certificates of completion of the training. The certificates of completion do not necessarily require a previous national certification process of the issuing organisation. MA monitoring system    At project completion   Double counting of participants in more than one training schemes organised by the same project should be excluded. Rule 1: Reporting by specific objective Forecast for selected projects and achieved values, both cumulative to date  (CPR Annex VII, Table 6).  -   -   In terms of links with common output indicators, indicator RCR81 is intended to be used together with RCO85.  The value reported for RCR81 can be equal to or lower than the value of RCO85 (for example in case some participants withdraw after the training started or in case not not all participants receive the final certification), but not higher.    NEW 157 60  157 true
```